# Google Guice - How to pass a parameter to a third party library Factory class

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

I am attempting to migrate from Spring to Guice for dependency injection.  Here is a sample snippet from a Spring xml config:

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.somethirdparty.MyConnectionFactory">
  <property name="connectionUrl" value="${urls.connectionUrl}"/>
  <property name="ackMode" value="unordered"/>
  <property name="timeout" ref="timeoutBean"/>
</bean>

<bean id="timeoutBean" class="java.lang.Integer">
  <constructor-arg value="10000"/>
</bean>
```

I am struggling with figuring out how to parameterize MyConnectionFactory with Google Guice.  I cannot annotate the constructor or methods of 'MyConnectionFactory' as this is a class provided by a 3rd party library.

After reading the [Guice FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) it seems to me the only option is to make a Factory for the Factory?  That seems silly to me!

Comment: Still no takers for this question? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to make a Factory for the MyConnectionFactory, but only if you actually need to vary the parameters passed to MyConnectionFactory at runtime. Otherwise, you can get away with making a `Provider`—which is a Factory after all, I guess—or its slimmer cousin [the @Provides Method](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods). (I'm guessing the class in question takes unspecific or primitive arguments, or else a [`toConstructor binding`](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ToConstructorBindings) is yet another possibility.)

The Factory would look like this:

```
public class MyConnectionFactoryFactory {
  @Inject Provider<SomeDependency> someDependencyProvider;

  public MyConnectionFactory create(String url) {
    return new MyConnectionFactory(someDependencyProvider.get(), url, 10000);
  }
}
```

The Provider would look identical, except it'd implement `Provider<MyConnectionFactory>` and `create` would instead be a zero-arg `get()`. You can bind that through `bind(MyConnectionFactory.class).toProvider(MyConnectionFactoryProvider.class)`.

However, if you know all your constructor parameters at configuration time, you could equally create a `@Provides` method in your Module, which would look like this:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override public void configure() { /* your configuration here */ }

  /* FYI: a @Provides method by any other name would return as sweet */
  @Provides MyConnectionFactory getConnectionFactory(SomeDependency dependency) {
    return new MyConnectionFactory(dependency, url, 10000);
  }
}
```

...which takes your "wrapper code" boilerplate to three extra non-blank lines. Remember, Guice will automatically bind any combination of `X`, `Provider<X>`, or `@Provides X` to any injection of `X` or `Provider<X>` automatically for you, so feel free to bind it however is most convenient.

Comment: Thanks a ton, it seems I misunderstood the usage of @Provides.  Your second example is exactly what I wanted to do, essentially load properties from a file at configuration time and pass them into the factory.